# Sequelize include association won't work (graphql)

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I have two models `User` and `FriendRequest`. `User` can have many `FriendRequests` and `FriendRequest` belongs to `User`. When I try to `User.findOne` and include `FriendRequest` I get

```
{
  ...
  FriendRequest: null
}
```

### models/User.js

```
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      tableName: "users"
    }
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.FriendRequest);
  };
```

### models/FriendRequest.js

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const FriendRequest = sequelize.define(
    "FriendRequest",
    {
      senderId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      receiverId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      UserId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {
      tableName: "friend_requests"
    }
  );
  FriendRequest.associate = function(models) {
    FriendRequest.belongsTo(models.User);
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return FriendRequest;
};
```

### graphql-modules/user.js

```
  type User {
    ...
    FriendRequest: [FriendRequest]
  }
```

### graphql-modules/friend_request.js

```
  type FriendRequest {
    id: Int!
    senderId: Int!
    receiverId: Int!
    status: Int!
    UserId: Int!
  }
```

### services/users_service.js

```
let searchUser = async (args) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
        where: args,
        include: [
          {
            model: FriendRequest
          }
        ]
      });
      let request = await FriendRequest.findAll({ where: { UserId: args.id } });
      console.log(request);
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Above, I added the request variable to see if I can query FriendRequest and yes I got the correct results.

I also tried to do

```
include: [
          {
            model: FriendRequest,
            where: {UserId: args.id}
          }
        ]
```

But it returns user=null;

I need the user variable to return an array of FriendRequests.
The rows exist on the database:
Id senderId  receiverId    status  UserId
7   5         2            0       5

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, the problem is that Sequelize generates the plural name of the association keeping the first letter capital, so to solve it I used an alias for the association.

```
// models/User.js
User.hasMany(models.FriendRequest, {
  as: 'friendRequests'
});

// graphql-modules/user.js
type User {
  ...
  friendRequests: [FriendRequest]
}

// services/users_service.js
User.findOne({
  where: args,
  include: [
    {
      model: FriendRequest,
      as: 'friendRequests'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Had been struggling with this for a few days.

Comment: Glad I could help :)